# How to remove this extra space in the tabPane in JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

[image: This is the case right now and I would like to remove it.]

This is the extra space in the tab pane next to the last tab option. I am using Scenebuilder to design the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extra space depends with tab pane header ,you have a way to hide it using css

```
.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color:transparent
}

.tab-pane{
    -fx-padding: 0 -1 -1 0
}
```

The result is:[image: remove extra space from tabPane]

Comment: This works for the table view, but I am not using table view in my design.

Comment: ah sorry, i was confused have you tried ***.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color:transparent
}** ?

Comment: There is still a space in the same area but now with a different color.

Comment: I changed the margin instead of the padding and it works! Thx